# Implementing tabs + swiping in android versions < 4.0

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to use tabs + swipe as primary navigation method for my app, but I want my app to be compatible with most of android versions. (i.e should be compatible with andorid 2.3 atleast)

I can't find any resources on how to do that !Please help

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Comment: @Harshit Syal. can you please share the code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. check out [android support library .](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)
2. try [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) , an extension of the compatibility library designed to facilitate the use of the action bar design pattern across all versions of Android with a single API.